# The structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$\mathbb{R}^n$ has very good topological property, it is locally compact,etc. However, I couldn't figure out why it has such good property aside from other topological space. Can anyone answer my question in the view of its construction?

Comment: This questions seems too vague to have a definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is mainly because what is considered a "good" property is mostly what is practical, and what is practical is *mostly* related to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For example, why being first-countable (or separable) is good? There are many useful spaces that are not first-countable, and there are such weird spaces that are...

But once you start dealing with something in practice, you start realizing that, for example, being at least locally "similar" to the real space is very useful. But what does it mean being similar? This is exactly where many definitions start coming from.

For example, compactness... This is another property that was initially developed to describe spaces for which some theorems from the real analysis are true.

If the real space were different, there would be different "good" properties, and it would still satisfy them.

Answer (score 0):

### Why is $ℝ^n$ so great?

1. It is a metric space.
2. The metric is complete.
3. It is finite dimensional.
4. It is homogenous.
5. It has vanishing Homotopy.
6. It is locally compact.
7. Its one-point compactification is the sphere.
8. It is second countable.